# SQL to return a string as a result of IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement, case

I have the following table on my database:

[image]

I would like to write a sql query that has the following logic:

```
IF QUIZZES<3, RETURN 'INCOMPLETE' ELSE 'COMPLETE'
```

How do I formulate my query?

Thanks

Comment: what programming language are you using?  You can't do that with SQL

Comment: Are you looking for, SELECT IF(QUIZZES<3, 'INCOMPLETE','COMPLETE') FROM yourTable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**CASE...ELSE...END**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html) or [**IF Statement**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html).

Try this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN QUIZZES < 3 THEN 'INCOMPLETE' ELSE 'COMPLETE' END) QuizStatus 
FROM tableA;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT IF(QUIZZES < 3, 'INCOMPLETE', 'COMPLETE') QuizStatus 
FROM tableA;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Name,STUDENT_ID,if(QUIZZES<3,'INCOMPLETE','COMPLETE') AS Status from table
```

Comment: Who is asking for a name?

Comment: @usermesamjosein, just for info if it helps..just guess